# How to render specific frame of the animation?

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I want a specific frame to be rendered using animation

```
batch.draw(Animation.getKeyFrame(time,true),x,y);
```

for example when I click somewhere I want the animation to change to the second image and not just loop the frames from the TextureAtlas.

UPDATE

```
public void newBitter(){
        Sprite spr= Pools.obtain(Sprite.class);
        bitters.add(spr);
        spr.setPosition(rX, Y);
    } //the sprites are not rendered I just need them for the c
```

oordinates

```
while(Iterator.hasNext()){
            Sprite sprite=Iterator.next();
            batch.draw(frames[frameCounter],sprite.getX(),sprite.getY());
            sprite.translateY(-300 * deltaTime);

            if(touched==true && gameObj.pos.x>=sprite.getX() && gameObj.pos.x<=sprite.getX()+82
                    && gameObj.pos.y>=sprite.getY() && gameObj.pos.y<=sprite.getY()+82){
                frameCounter=1;
                } //here I render the frames/animation based on the sprite coordinates, If the sprite is clicked the counter for the frames ==1 or +=1
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep all animation frames in a collection and then modify the current frame id due to conditions like:

```
    Animation animation;

    ...

    TextureRegion[] frames = animation.getKeyFrames();
    int currentFrameId = 0;

    ...

    if( clickedOnSomething() ) //let the clickedOnSomething method return true when clicked
    {
        currentFrameId++; //or another change due to some conditions
    }

    ...

    batch.draw(frames[currentFrameId], x, y);
```

Comment: it works but I have many animations and I want to change the frame to the animation that I click, so basically what happens is that when I click one animation every other one is gonna change frame.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your ClickListener?

Comment: Why you iterate over all animations, using flags and so on? Read about ClickListener click() method - it will give you an asynchronous method to change exactly one **clicked** object modifying its inner **currentFrameId** parameter you will add to this - then all you need to do is in the render render just this fram as I've showed above